# Filtering list_blob() with date information

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I have and Azure container with thousands of images with different creation dates. I would like to do a `container_client.list_blobs()` with the Python SDK from Azure that only creates the list with those dates. Getting all the data and then iterating over all the data to select only blobs created after certain date is too slow as it is O(n). Is there any parameter like "start_date" or something like that that I could use?

I looked into the code and saw that there is something like ChangeFeed but it turned out to be under development.

Answer (score 0):

> Filtering list_blob() with date information

You can use the below code to list the blobs with filtering with date.

Here, it is listing all of the blobs in the container and then filtering them depending on when they were created. We retrieve the creation time of each blob using the **`blob.creation_time`** property and compare it to the **`start_date`** variable. If the blob's formation time is earlier than the start date, it will print the blob's name.

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = 'xxxx'
container_name = 'output'

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
start_date = datetime(2023, 8, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blobs = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blobs:
      if blob.creation_time > start_date:
        print(blob.name)
```

**Output:**

```
submittedpaginated/merged.csv
submittedpaginated/part-00000-1cexxx-4eeb-8f94-88abecdb86b5-c000.csv
submittedpaginated/part-00000-347xxxxxxx-4cd8-821c-fbceaa770a46-c000.csv
submittedpaginated/part-00000-cxxxxxx42ac-bcf9-bf7b690ba8c6-c000.csv
```

[image]

Comment: The issue with that is that it still will have to pass through all the data to detect if something was created after a date. So that pretty much leaves us with the same O(n) complexity.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Unfortunately, there is no parameter like "start_date" that you can use to filter the list of blobs based on the creation date. As you mentioned, iterating over all the data to select only blobs created after a specific date is O(n) and can be slow for large containers.

Comment: The above code retrieves the `creation time` of each blob using the blob.creation_time property and compares it to the start_date variable. If the blob's creation time is later than the start date, it will print the blob's name. Although this still has O(n) complexity, it avoids retrieving all the data and then iterating over it, which can be faster for large containers.